# Can AES generate arbitrary ciphertext by choosing plaintext and key?

Tags: aes

All my confusion comes from the following example:

```py
key='c086e08ad8ee0ebe7c2320099cfec9eea9a346a108570a4f6494cfe7c2a30ee1'.decode('hex')
IV='78228d4760a3675aa08d47694f88f639'.decode('hex')
pad=lambda S: S+chr(16-len(S)%16)*(16-len(S)%16)
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
cipher=AES.new(key,AES.MODE_CBC,IV)
msg='NO, NOT SECRET!'
cip=cipher.encrypt(pad(msg))
```

then cip is "IS THIS SECRET??". Therefore, I don’t know if this is purely coincidental or there is some kind of algorithm that can generate the ciphertext I want by properly selecting the key and plaintext.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273) (don't just change your question to "How").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a puzzle, isn't it? The trick is in first decrypting the `IS THIS SECRET??` string using the block cipher. Then the trickster can alter the resulting random "plaintext" by changing the IV. Look up CBC mode to see how.

Finally, the trickster just need to add an encrypted padding block to the ciphertext. OK, since this was probably an assignment that you needed to figure out, please try and create such a weird ciphertext yourself and make it decrypt to a special message of your own.